# Ubuntu freezes when it gets locked while playing video on fullscreen

Tags: 14.04, video, freeze, fullscreen, lock

I have it set on if it's inactive for 5 minutes, it'll get locked. I don't really mind this, it's what I used to do in Windows, too. What I do mind is, whenever it gets locked when videos are in fullscreen (Chrome YouTube videos and Ubuntu default player videos - haven't checked on VLC yet), after I enter my password and login, the video goes on playing, but I can't do anything. I see the video, I hear the sounds, but I have no control whatsoever.

Is there a way to prevent it from freezing when it locks? Or should I just turn off the automatic lock after five minutes? Or is there anything else I can do, apart from shutting down my PC, by hand, and re-booting? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A way to prevent Ubuntu from fading out and locking the screen is a small application called `caffeine-plus`. It is available from a `webupd8` repository.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install caffeine-plus`